# How to define a layout with two parts in my case

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I would like to define a layout which looks like this:

[image]

What I mean is to have the yellow area on top of screen, keep it always visible on screen, while, the green area is a `<ScrollView>`.

I am thinking to define two separate layout files, e.g. **yellow_area.xml** & **green_area.xml**, and includes them in one **main.xml**.

But how to keep yellow area always visible & have green area scrollable? (That's to make yellow area looks like it is above green area)

Comment: Any reason why you don't wanna use nested layouts (Linear / Relative) in one xml? Or you wanna use fragments?

Comment: Because I will reuse each layout in other parts of my project, that's why I include them for this particular main.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am thinking to define two separate layout files, e.g. yellow_area.xml & green_area.xml, and includes them in one main.xml.

If you are wanting to re-use one or both of them then doing this or using `fragments` is a fine idea...whichever works best in your case.

> But how to keep yellow area always visible & have green area scrollable? (That's to make yellow area looks like it is above green area)

You should be able to accomplish this by using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and using the property

```
android:layout_below="@id/topLayout"
```

in the `<include>` tag for your "greeen `layout` assuming that `topLayout` is the `id` of your "yellow" `layout`.

**Edit**

I think my above answer didn't work due to the number of `View`s inside of the included `layout`. Using a `LinearLayout` as the `parent layout` and using `layout_weight` inside of each child `layout` ( and `ListView` fixes the problem. Something like

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <!--included a title_layout-->
   <include
        android:id="@+id/upper_area"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   
        layout="@layout/title_layout"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>    // add weight here 

    <!--Listview below title_layout-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/data_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75"  />      // and here


</LinearLayout>
```

Using `layout_weight` with a `vertical` orientation the `height` must be set to `0dp` (`layout_width="0dp"` for horizontal orientation)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I got the upper yellow layout occupy the whole screen. I use "wrap_content" for layout_height everywhere.

Comment: Can you post the xml you have for this `layout`? Not sure why I got downvoted

Comment: Check here, I asked again in a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594155/the-included-layout-occupies-the-whole-screen  it contains my source code.

Comment: In the new post I use <LinearLayout> , I also tried <RelativeLayout> , the result is the same, I got the upper layout occupies the whole screen

Comment: It shows up correctly when I copy/paste into my editor. But you said that you have many more `TextView`s...that could be the problem. Try using `layout_weight`. Give your "upper-layout" something like `layout_weight=".25"` then `.75` to the `ListView`. You will need to change the `height` of both to `0dp`

Comment: Yes, after gave the layout_weight to upper & lower parts, it works well. Thanks. Could you please make an answer to my new post so that I can accept your answer :)  Also  please update the current answer. I will accept both

Comment: Will do...just give me a few minutes. Might be better to delete one then you can accept and upvote if you want

Comment: Sure, I will delete my new post. You just need to update the current answer with layout_weight, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the layout below with the framelayout as a holder for your fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

     <!--Whatever you want in the scrollview-->
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where to put the yellow area?

Comment: You abstract the yellow area out to a fragment so you can reuse it.  You could even have the green layout as a fragment as well.

Comment: Using the fragment method, you can reuse them anywhere in your application dynamically or through xml inflation like this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Play with the weights to change how much each part should take up.

```
<LinearLayout
    ...android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        ...android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <ScrollView
        ...android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"/>
/>
```

I just included the important parts, you will want to fill in more information based on your needs. That textview can be anything, it looks like it may need to be something like another layout to put that picture in there with the text next to it.

Comment: Ooops, looks like someone else responded with something similar